# Error with Subsonic attempting to convert Timespan to String

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

using Subsonic v3.0.0.3 with MS SQL 2008 (10.0.2531) and have two columns in a table 'Date' and 'Time' (*not* DateTime columns) and when the ActiveRecord SingleOrDefault (line 14110) attempts to load the object (via a given pkid) this error is thrown;

```
"Object of type 'System.TimeSpan' cannot be converted to type 'System.String'."
```

Any idea on how to work around this? The part that fuzzles me is [MS SQL doesn't](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx) have a 'Timespan' column type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date and Time column types are not currently supported in SubSonic 3

Comment: Is that on a FAQ or something somewhere? Just saying perhaps things like that should be documented somewhere.

Comment: I don't know if that's been mentioned anywhere outside of GitHub issues and blog posts. I'll see if I can add it to the docs wiki.