# Subsonic ignoring TimeSpan property

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3, subsonic-simplerepository

For some reason the TimeSpan property on my class is not being persisted into the database by Subsonic it is simply being ignored!? All other properties are being saved OK. I am using SimpleRepository and RunMigrations, Subsonic v3.0.0.3.

```
public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
```

Are TimeSpans not supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TimeSpan is not a valid 2005/2008 SQL data type.

Store it as a numeric based SQL data type. Convert your TimeSpan to an appropriate duration based on the accuracy you require:

```
// Define an interval of 1 day, 15+ hours.
TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan(1, 15, 42, 45, 750); 
Console.WriteLine("Value of TimeSpan: {0}", interval);
Console.WriteLine("{0:N5} minutes, as follows:", interval.TotalMinutes);
```

Beware that there is a distinct difference between interval.Minutes and interval.TotalMinutes!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalminutes.aspx

Thus:

```
// my duration
int duration = Time.TotalMinutes;
// now insert this into the database
```

Comment: Thanks but as I am using SimpleRepository would that mean having to change the data type of my object purely for the purpose of inserting the data in the database and then casting it everytime I want to use it - unless I am misunderstanding?

Comment: Hi ProNotion. My bad. I misread your question. 

Another user has a similar (ActiveRecord rather than SimpleRepository) TimeSpan conversion issue and the answer from John Sheehan might relate to your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448626/error-with-subsonic-attempting-to-convert-timespan-to-string

Maybe you should raise this question on the SubSonic Google Group: http://groups.google.com/group/subsonicproject

Comment: On reflection your recommendation works fine for me by storing an integer representation of the number of milliseconds in the TimeSpan. Thanks